# Rubberduck's "Rename" refactoring implementation

Tags: c#, antlr, rubberduck

Knowing [who's using what](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84888/whos-using-what-where-turning-code-into-symbols), and where, I've implemented a "Rename" refactoring for [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com).

[image: Please specify a new name for procedure 'FizzBuzz'.]

It works great - it needs further extensive testing, but the preliminary tests are very, very exciting.

There are a few things I'm not sure I like though:

- The entire logic is implemented in the `Rubberduck.UI` namespace. The "[Extract Method](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80568/rubberducks-extract-method-refactoring-implementation)" refactoring logic is also implemented under that namespace (under `Rubberduck.UI.Refactorings.ExtractMethod`) - I think I might be violating SRP with these presenter classes, but I'm not sure it's worth the trouble. Any thoughts?
- I don't know whether/how it's possible to actually replace tokens in the parse tree, so the renaming actually boils down to a very very localized search & replace... and the implementation is **ugly beyond words** - and I'm not sure how to go about making it right.
- The code acquiring the target identifier looks like it could get cleaner... but how?

```
namespace Rubberduck.UI.Refactorings.Rename
{
    public class RenamePresenter
    {
        private readonly VBE _vbe;
        private readonly IRenameView _view;
        private readonly Declarations _declarations;
        private readonly QualifiedSelection _selection;

        public RenamePresenter(VBE vbe, IRenameView view, Declarations declarations, QualifiedSelection selection)
        {
            _vbe = vbe;
            _view = view;
            _view.OkButtonClicked += OnOkButtonClicked;

            _declarations = declarations;
            _selection = selection;
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            AcquireTarget(_selection);
            _view.ShowDialog();
        }

        private static readonly DeclarationType[] ModuleDeclarationTypes =
            {
                DeclarationType.Class,
                DeclarationType.Module
            };

        private void OnOkButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ModuleDeclarationTypes.Contains(_view.Target.DeclarationType))
            {
                RenameModule();
            }
            else
            {
                RenameDeclaration();
            }

            RenameUsages();
        }

        private void RenameModule()
        {
            try
            {
                var module = _vbe.FindCodeModules(_view.Target.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName).Single();
                module.Name = _view.NewName;
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(RubberduckUI.RenameDialog_ModuleRenameError, RubberduckUI.RenameDialog_Caption);
            }
        }

        private void RenameDeclaration()
        {
            var module = _vbe.FindCodeModules(_view.Target.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName).First();
            var content = module.get_Lines(_view.Target.Selection.StartLine, 1);
            var newContent = GetReplacementLine(content, _view.Target.IdentifierName, _view.NewName);
            module.ReplaceLine(_view.Target.Selection.StartLine, newContent);
        }

        private void RenameUsages()
        {
            var modules = _view.Target.References.GroupBy(r => r.QualifiedModuleName);
            foreach (var grouping in modules)
            {
                var module = _vbe.FindCodeModules(grouping.Key).First();
                foreach (var line in grouping.GroupBy(reference => reference.Selection.StartLine))
                {
                    var content = module.get_Lines(line.Key, 1);
                    var newContent = GetReplacementLine(content, _view.Target.IdentifierName, _view.NewName);
                    module.ReplaceLine(line.Key, newContent);
                }
            }
        }

        private string GetReplacementLine(string content, string target, string newName)
        {
            // until we figure out how to replace actual tokens,
            // this is going to have to be done the ugly way...

            // what we're trying to avoid here,
            // is to replace all instances of "Foo" in "Foo = FooBar" when target is "Foo".

            var result = ' ' + content;
            if (result.Contains(' ' + target))
            {
                result = result.Replace(' ' + target, ' ' + newName);
            }
            if (result.Contains(target + ' '))
            {
                result = result.Replace(target + ' ', newName + ' ');
            }
            if (result.Contains(target + '.'))
            {
                result = result.Replace(target + '.', newName + '.');
            }
            else if (result.Contains('.' + target))
            {
                result = result.Replace('.' + target, '.'+ newName);
            }

            if (result.Contains('(' + target))
            {
                result = result.Replace('(' + target, '(' + newName);
            }

            if (result.Contains(":=" + target))
            {
                result = result.Replace(":=" + target, ":=" + newName);
            }

            if (result.Contains(target + '!'))
            {
                result = result.Replace(target + '!', newName + '!');
            }
            else if (result.Contains('!' + target))
            {
                result = result.Replace('!' + target, '!' + newName);
            }

            return result.Substring(1);
        }

        private static readonly DeclarationType[] ProcedureDeclarationTypes =
            {
                DeclarationType.Procedure,
                DeclarationType.Function,
                DeclarationType.PropertyGet,
                DeclarationType.PropertyLet,
                DeclarationType.PropertySet
            };

        private void AcquireTarget(QualifiedSelection selection)
        {
            var targets = _declarations.Items.Where(declaration =>
                declaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName == selection.QualifiedName
                && (declaration.Selection.Contains(selection.Selection))
                || declaration.References.Any(r => r.Selection.Contains(selection.Selection)))
                .ToList();

            var nonProcTarget = targets.Where(t => !ProcedureDeclarationTypes.Contains(t.DeclarationType)).ToList();
            if (nonProcTarget.Any())
            {
                _view.Target = nonProcTarget.First();
            }
            else
            {
                _view.Target = targets.FirstOrDefault();
            }

            if (_view.Target == null)
            {
                // no valid selection? no problem - let's rename the module:
                _view.Target = _declarations.Items.SingleOrDefault(declaration =>
                    declaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName == selection.QualifiedName
                    && ModuleDeclarationTypes.Contains(declaration.DeclarationType));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I definitely need a different approach for the `GetReplacementLine` method; I thought of using regex, but I'd rather not. Or should I? Are there other alternatives?

I've tagged this with [antlr](/questions/tagged/antlr) because my `Declaration` object *does* expose a `RuleContext` object that I'm just not using here... anyone familiar with ANTLR knows if there's something I should know that would make my life easier here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**GetReplacementLine()**

Instead of using `String.Replace()` you should check out the [`TokenRewriteStream`](http://www.antlr3.org/api/ActionScript/org/antlr/runtime/TokenRewriteStream.html) mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624231).

If you need to use `String.Replace()` then you should omit the not needed call to `String.Contains()`. If the string which should be replaced isn't found in the 'content', the unchanged 'content' will be returned. In addition it will speed up the execution because it does not have to search for the token twice.

But you also have duplicated code inside this method, so it would be better to extract this into 2 separate methods. One replacing the searchterm with a passed prefix and the other with a passed postfix.

Like:

```
private string PostfixReplace(string content, string token, string newName, string postFix)
{
    return content.Replace(token + postFix, newName + postFix);
}
```

**AcquireTarget()**

There is no need to call `ToList()` on the result of the Linq `Where` clauses because you only need either `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`. The call to `ToList()` will slow down the execution because every item will be qualified but you only need the first one.

**var**

IMHO you are misusing the `var` keyword, because you use it all the time. Assume you need to dig into this class after not touching it for a few weeks, you won't know what most of the types will be, because it isn't obvious what type the right side is, e.g

> ```
> var targets = _declarations.Items.Where(declaration =>
>     declaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName == selection.QualifiedName
>     && (declaration.Selection.Contains(selection.Selection))
>     || declaration.References.Any(r => r.Selection.Contains(selection.Selection)))
>     .ToList();
> ```

Comment: `TokenRewriteStream` just by the name of it, sounds exactly like what I'm after!!! I just hope it's in ANTLR4 and works in the C# target :)

Comment: as for the `var` bit - indeed, I use it all the time.. but it seems clear to me that that specific chunk is selecting a `Declaration` instance...