# Extract Method: A refactored refactoring

Tags: c#, rubberduck

This post is somewhat of a follow-up to [Rubberduck's "Extract Method" refactoring implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80568/rubberducks-extract-method-refactoring-implementation).

A tremendous amount of things have changed since version 1.2, when this feature was first introduced - the more important thing being the advent of the `Declarations` API, which implies that the feature now not only gets an ANTLR parse tree to play with, but also a strongly-typed `IEnumerable<Declaration>` collection, each with their `References` resolved (see [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/84888/23788) for more details on that specific part).

This means I no longer need to walk the parse tree, so I removed a tremendous amount of code here, and simplified the "who's used where" logic in unspeakable ways.

Thing is, I'm sure it can *still* be tremendously improved.

```
namespace Rubberduck.UI.Refactorings.ExtractMethod
{
    public class ExtractMethodPresenter
    {
        private readonly IExtractMethodDialog _view;

        private readonly IEnumerable<ExtractedParameter> _input;
        private readonly IEnumerable<ExtractedParameter> _output;
        private readonly List<Declaration> _locals;
        private readonly List<Declaration> _toRemoveFromSource;

        private readonly string _selectedCode;
        private readonly QualifiedSelection _selection;

        private readonly IActiveCodePaneEditor _editor;
        private readonly Declaration _member;

        private readonly HashSet<Declaration> _usedInSelection;
        private readonly HashSet<Declaration> _usedBeforeSelection;
        private readonly HashSet<Declaration> _usedAfterSelection;

        public ExtractMethodPresenter(IActiveCodePaneEditor editor, IExtractMethodDialog view, Declaration member, QualifiedSelection selection, Declarations declarations)
        {
            _editor = editor;
            _view = view;
            _member = member;
            _selection = selection;

            _selectedCode = _editor.GetLines(selection.Selection);

            var inScopeDeclarations = declarations.Items.Where(item => item.ParentScope == member.Scope).ToList();

            var inSelection = inScopeDeclarations.SelectMany(item => item.References)
                                                 .Where(item => selection.Selection.Contains(item.Selection))
                                                 .ToList();

            _usedInSelection = new HashSet<Declaration>(inScopeDeclarations.Where(item =>
                item.References.Any(reference => inSelection.Contains(reference))));

            _usedBeforeSelection = new HashSet<Declaration>(inScopeDeclarations.Where(item => 
                item.References.Any(reference => reference.Selection.StartLine < selection.Selection.StartLine)));

            _usedAfterSelection = new HashSet<Declaration>(inScopeDeclarations.Where(item =>
                item.References.Any(reference => reference.Selection.StartLine > selection.Selection.EndLine)));

            // identifiers used inside selection and before selection (or if it's a parameter) are candidates for parameters:
            var input = inScopeDeclarations.Where(item => 
                _usedInSelection.Contains(item) && (_usedBeforeSelection.Contains(item) || item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Parameter)).ToList();

            // identifiers used inside selection and after selection are candidates for return values:
            var output = inScopeDeclarations.Where(item => 
                _usedInSelection.Contains(item) && _usedAfterSelection.Contains(item))
                .ToList();

            // identifiers used only inside and/or after selection are candidates for locals:
            _locals = inScopeDeclarations.Where(item => item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Parameter && (
                item.References.All(reference => inSelection.Contains(reference))
                || (_usedAfterSelection.Contains(item) && (!_usedBeforeSelection.Contains(item)))))
                .ToList();

            // locals that are only used in selection are candidates for being moved into the new method:
            _toRemoveFromSource = _locals.Where(item => !_usedAfterSelection.Contains(item)).ToList();

            _output = output.Select(declaration =>
                new ExtractedParameter(declaration.AsTypeName, ExtractedParameter.PassedBy.ByRef, declaration.IdentifierName));

            _input = input.Where(declaration => !output.Contains(declaration))
                .Select(declaration =>
                    new ExtractedParameter(declaration.AsTypeName, ExtractedParameter.PassedBy.ByVal, declaration.IdentifierName));
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            PrepareView();
            if (_view.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return;
            }

            ExtractMethod();
        }

        private void PrepareView()
        {
            _view.MethodName = "Method1";
            _view.Inputs = _input.ToList();
            _view.Outputs = _output.ToList();
            _view.Locals =
                _locals.Select(
                    variable =>
                        new ExtractedParameter(variable.AsTypeName, ExtractedParameter.PassedBy.ByVal, variable.IdentifierName))
                    .ToList();

            var returnValues = new[] {new ExtractedParameter(string.Empty, ExtractedParameter.PassedBy.ByVal)}
                .Union(_view.Outputs)
                .Union(_view.Inputs)
                .ToList();

            _view.ReturnValues = returnValues;
            _view.ReturnValue = (_output.Any() && !_output.Skip(1).Any())
                ? _output.Single()
                : returnValues.First();

            _view.RefreshPreview += _view_RefreshPreview;
            _view.OnRefreshPreview();
        }

        private void ExtractMethod()
        {
            _editor.DeleteLines(_selection.Selection);
            _editor.ReplaceLine(_selection.Selection.StartLine, GetMethodCall());

            var insertionLine = _member.Context.GetSelection().EndLine - _selection.Selection.LineCount + 2;
            _editor.InsertLines(insertionLine, GetExtractedMethod());

            // assumes these are declared *before* the selection...
            var offset = 0;
            foreach (var declaration in _toRemoveFromSource.OrderBy(e => e.Selection.StartLine))
            {
                var target = new Selection(
                    declaration.Selection.StartLine - offset,
                    declaration.Selection.StartColumn,
                    declaration.Selection.EndLine - offset,
                    declaration.Selection.EndColumn);

                _editor.DeleteLines(target);
                offset += declaration.Selection.LineCount;
            }
        }

        private static readonly IEnumerable<string> ValueTypes = new[]
        {
            Tokens.Boolean,
            Tokens.Byte,
            Tokens.Currency,
            Tokens.Date,
            Tokens.Decimal,
            Tokens.Double,
            Tokens.Integer,
            Tokens.Long,
            Tokens.LongLong,
            Tokens.Single,
            Tokens.String
        };

        private void _view_RefreshPreview(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var hasReturnValue = _view.ReturnValue != null && _view.ReturnValue.Name != ExtractedParameter.None;
            _view.CanSetReturnValue =
                hasReturnValue && !ValueTypes.Contains(_view.ReturnValue.TypeName);

            GeneratePreview();
        }

        private void GeneratePreview()
        {
            _view.Preview = GetExtractedMethod();
        }

        private string GetMethodCall()
        {
            string result;
            var returnValueName = _view.ReturnValue.Name;
            var argsList = string.Join(", ", _view.Parameters.Select(p => p.Name));
            if (returnValueName != ExtractedParameter.None)
            {
                var setter = _view.SetReturnValue ? Tokens.Set + ' ' : string.Empty;
                result = setter + returnValueName + " = " + _view.MethodName + '(' + argsList + ')';
            }
            else
            {
                result = _view.MethodName + ' ' + argsList;
            }

            return "    " + result; // todo: smarter indentation
        }

        private string GetExtractedMethod()
        {
            var newLine = Environment.NewLine;

            var access = _view.Accessibility.ToString();
            var keyword = Tokens.Sub;
            var asTypeClause = string.Empty;

            var isFunction = _view.ReturnValue != null && _view.ReturnValue.Name != ExtractedParameter.None;
            if (isFunction)
            {
                keyword = Tokens.Function;
                asTypeClause = Tokens.As + ' ' + _view.ReturnValue.TypeName;
            }

            var parameters = "(" + string.Join(", ", _view.Parameters) + ")";

            var result = access + ' ' + keyword + ' ' + _view.MethodName + parameters + ' ' + asTypeClause + newLine;

            var localConsts = _locals.Where(e => e.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Constant)
                .Cast<ValuedDeclaration>()
                .Select(e => "    " + Tokens.Const + ' ' + e.IdentifierName + ' ' + Tokens.As + ' ' + e.AsTypeName + " = " + e.Value);

            var localVariables = _locals.Where(e => e.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Variable)
                .Where(e => _view.Parameters.All(param => param.Name != e.IdentifierName))
                .Select(e => e.Context)
                .Cast<VBAParser.VariableSubStmtContext>()
                .Select(e => "    " + Tokens.Dim + ' ' + e.ambiguousIdentifier().GetText() + 
                    (e.LPAREN() == null 
                        ? string.Empty 
                        : e.LPAREN().GetText() + (e.subscripts() == null ? string.Empty : e.subscripts().GetText()) + e.RPAREN().GetText()) + ' ' + 
                        (e.asTypeClause() == null ? string.Empty : e.asTypeClause().GetText()));
            var locals = string.Join(newLine, localConsts.Union(localVariables)
                            .Where(local => !_selectedCode.Contains(local)).ToArray()) + newLine;

            result += locals + _selectedCode + newLine;

            if (isFunction)
            {
                // return value by assigning the method itself:
                var setter = _view.SetReturnValue ? Tokens.Set + ' ' : string.Empty;
                result += "    " + setter + _view.MethodName + " = " + _view.ReturnValue.Name + newLine;
            }

            result += Tokens.End + ' ' + keyword + newLine;

            return newLine + result + newLine;
        }
    }
}
```

The good news is that this rewrite solves a number of issues that have been identified since the initial release of the feature... but a number of things jump at me in the constructor and fields, and I'm particularly interested in the following:

- I feel like the constructor is doing too much work. Should I move its logic elsewhere?
- `GetExtractedMethod` is... *bleh*. How can I turn this ugliness into something pretty?
- Anything else?

Note: The project uses an [antlr](/questions/tagged/antlr) grammar to generate a parser; the generated class is called `VBAParser`, and has a nested class for each grammar rule (e.g. `VBAParser.VariableSubStmtContext`). As much as I'd love these rules to follow C# naming conventions, it isn't something that's possible. Parser rules are `camelCase`, and lexer tokens are `YELLCASE`; that's just how it is.

---

For context, here's the `ExtractedParameter` class:

```
namespace Rubberduck.UI.Refactorings.ExtractMethod
{
    public class ExtractedParameter
    {
        public enum PassedBy
        {
            ByRef,
            ByVal
        }

        public static readonly string None = RubberduckUI.ExtractMethod_OutputNone;

        private readonly string _name;
        private readonly string _typeName;
        private readonly PassedBy _passedBy;

        public ExtractedParameter(string typeName, PassedBy passedBy, string name = null)
        {
            _name = name ?? None;
            _typeName = typeName;
            _passedBy = passedBy;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }

        public string TypeName
        {
            get { return _typeName; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _passedBy.ToString() + ' ' + Name + ' ' + Tokens.As + ' ' + TypeName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I love "YELLCASE". haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That constructor looks kind of messy.  What I would do here is create a field `_declarations` and assign it in the constructor:

```
public ExtractMethodPresenter(IActiveCodePaneEditor editor, IExtractMethodDialog view, Declaration member, QualifiedSelection selection, Declarations declarations)
{
    _editor = editor;
    _view = view;
    _member = member;
    _selection = selection;
    _declarations = declarations;

    InitializeFields();
}
```

`InitializeFields` might look something like this:

```
private void InitializeFields()
{
    _selectedCode = _editor.GetLines(selection.Selection);

    var inScopeDeclarations = _declarations.Items.Where(item => item.ParentScope == member.Scope).ToList();

    var inSelection = inScopeDeclarations.SelectMany(item => item.References)
                                         .Where(item => _selection.Selection.Contains(item.Selection))
                                         .ToList();

    _usedInSelection = new HashSet<Declaration>(inScopeDeclarations.Where(item =>
        item.References.Any(reference => inSelection.Contains(reference))));

    _usedBeforeSelection = new HashSet<Declaration>(inScopeDeclarations.Where(item => 
        item.References.Any(reference => reference.Selection.StartLine < _selection.Selection.StartLine)));

    _usedAfterSelection = new HashSet<Declaration>(inScopeDeclarations.Where(item =>
        item.References.Any(reference => reference.Selection.StartLine > _selection.Selection.EndLine)));

    // identifiers used inside selection and before selection (or if it's a parameter) are candidates for parameters:
    var input = inScopeDeclarations.Where(item => 
        _usedInSelection.Contains(item) && (_usedBeforeSelection.Contains(item) || item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Parameter)).ToList();

    // identifiers used inside selection and after selection are candidates for return values:
    var output = inScopeDeclarations.Where(item => 
        _usedInSelection.Contains(item) && _usedAfterSelection.Contains(item))
        .ToList();

    // identifiers used only inside and/or after selection are candidates for locals:
    _locals = inScopeDeclarations.Where(item => item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Parameter && (
        item.References.All(reference => inSelection.Contains(reference))
        || (_usedAfterSelection.Contains(item) && (!_usedBeforeSelection.Contains(item)))))
        .ToList();

    // locals that are only used in selection are candidates for being moved into the new method:
    _toRemoveFromSource = _locals.Where(item => !_usedAfterSelection.Contains(item)).ToList();

    _output = output.Select(declaration =>
        new ExtractedParameter(declaration.AsTypeName, ExtractedParameter.PassedBy.ByRef, declaration.IdentifierName));

    _input = input.Where(declaration => !output.Contains(declaration))
        .Select(declaration =>
            new ExtractedParameter(declaration.AsTypeName, ExtractedParameter.PassedBy.ByVal, declaration.IdentifierName));
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a need to keep a reference to `declarations`. Why not just pass it along to `InitializeFields`? I.e. `InitializeFields(declarations)`

Comment: @RubberDuck That is an idea too.  However, this variable can be very large, so you might want to pass by reference.